# Passing parameters to Hypercorn when Quart is used in development mode

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-logging, quart, hypercorn

When running say:

```
export QUART_APP=hello-world:app
quart run
```

As far as I understand you actually have three logging mechanisms in place, one set up by Hypercorn, another set up by Quart itself and another one set by AsyncIO module. In my case, in addition to the aforementioned, I have my own application-level logging mechanism.

I'd like all the logs to be consistent in terms of how they appear (e.g. format etc.), how can I pass a log format to Hypercorn when using "quart run"? the only way I saw this is done is by creating a configuration file, but I am not sure if Hypercorn will even load it when it is spawned by quart.

I can always get the loggers directly by using logging.getLogger('hypercorn.access') and logging.getLogger('hypercorn.error') and forcefully set any attributes after the fact but that a bit ugly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this it currently unsupported. However, I submitted the following PR on Github to add support for this:

https://github.com/pgjones/hypercorn/pull/133